# Facebook: iframe inside iframe?

Tags: facebook, jquery, iframe, xhtml

Is it possible to insert a page as facebook canvas, which contains its own iframe?

I want to make fb fanpage like this:

https://www.facebook.com/pepsi?v=app_4949752878

and insert an ajax file upload inside, or other plugin which needs to use iframe.

Will fb allow me to do this? Is it possible to have iframes in iframes from browser's point of view?

Theoretically it should work just fine, but maybe there will be some cross browser issues?

Comment: you can post your own answer, and mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be just fine on a Facebook app. As far as I know there are no limits to iframes within iframes (embedded within other HTML pages of course).

You don't want any of your iframes to have the same id value. However it's unlikely you'll have conflicts, since Facebook generates long id's such as: `app_runner_fb_https_4e71c7dc372fe0419799713`

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question, as I do some research and test it in FB iframe across browsers (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari).

So the answer is simple as chrishall78 answered: yes you can, and it works in FB iframe.

The only limitation is when you want to access iframe (as always security reasons). You need to have exactly the same domain (protocols https and http are different, also ports must be the same).

If you follow this rules you can use whatever iframe-based plugin you want!

I hope my research will help other fb/iframe devs.